# Looking for suitable method to backup home computer to remote server

Tags: backup

Well I'm quite new to linux and notice I sometimes crap all over my system.
Perhaps not breaking it but definitely leaves it very polluted.
So I would like to make backups that is stored on a remote server that's running ubuntu server 16.04.

Most preferred way would be to initiate the backup manually while leaving the task it self automatic if that is possible. (So I don't accidentally backup a polluted/broken state)

Should also allow for an easy way to restore a previous backed up copy.

Alternatively I could store the backup on a local drive depending on what's most suitable.

How should I go about to achieve this if I may ask?

Comment: You're looking for a full recovery, not just files?  Have you considered installing your base system, and then use VM's for your crapping?

Comment: Not quite really, could perhaps be an idea to use a VM but it's more in the daily use I tend to mess up my system. Add wrong program or make a change somewhere and not entirely sure how to revert those changes.  Or something else goes wrong along the line. So would like a full recovery mainly the most common work directories, I tend to slowly learn from my mistakes might need to make them a few times thought.